# How to convert .xls file to .xlsx file in python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

How to convert .xls file to .xlsx file using python packages openpyxl and xlrd?
and how can we save the new .xlsx file into directory ?

Comment: Please add in some code that you have tried, Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use http://www.python-excel.org/
try read their documentation
its easy
thank you

or you can use this: https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd

or simply you can do:

```
sudo pip install pyexcel-cli pyexcel-xls pyexcel-xlsx
pyexcel transcode xls-file.xls xlsx-file.xlsx
```